# What is an efficient algorithm for finding the number of shapes in a binary image?

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision

For a [binary image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_image), I am interested in a way to efficiently count the number of individual shapes present in the image. Also as an adjacent question, how can one fit each shape that is present in the image in a square?

Pseudocode is most welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't answer the second half, but if the first half defines a "shape" as contiguous pixels of a certain color, here's what I do.  Maintain an array for the whole image, indicating which pixels have been "seen".  (A bool[,] would do the trick, in C#-speak.)

Then begin iterating over each pixel.  If it's been seen already, skip it.

Otherwise, if it's not yet been seen and it's the "non-shape" color, mark it seen and move on.

Otherwise, it hasn't been seen and is a shape.  From here, spider out in each of the four compass directions.  If you reach a seen pixel, stop and turn back (this prevents an infinite loop from occurring).  If the pixel is the non-shape color, mark the pixel seen and stop immediately.  Otherwise, the pixel is a shape color.  Mark it seen and add it to whatever "shape definition" data you are building up.

Once this process completes, you have discovered one shape.  Store it somewhere, and continue searching.  All of the pixels in that shape should now be marked seen, and will no longer be considered by the algorithm.

This algorithm for shape-discovery once a shape-color pixel has been located is inherently recursive, and for large shapes may overflow the stack.  It may be appropriate to use a heap-based stack implementation to perform the entire shape search.

(If you consider diagonally-adjacent pixels enough to link two shapes into one, simply search all eight adjacent pixels instead of just the four horizontally- and vertically-adjacent ones.)

Answer (score 3):

One possible notion of "shape" is connected components.  In that case, a union-find algorithm will give you want you want: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_Component_Labeling.  If you also want the X and Y extents, union-find can be extended to keep track of those.

Answer (score 2):

Do Blobing of the image data, you will get each shape with all pixels and extents [RECT of the shape]

If your image has a shape inside shape, then blobing will treat both as individual shapes.

If you need code send me mail, will be happy to share.